# How to place a JavaScript variable value in HTML input tag's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, simple-html-dom

```
$( window ).on( "load", function(){
        var token_val= document.getElementsByName("token")[0].value;

        var real_data = "<input type='hidden' name='token' value='NEED VLAUE OF token_val HERE'>";

        $('form').append(real_data);
});
```

This my code. I need to set value on input tag as variable token_val 's value.

Comment: Just concatenate the value in string like this -- `... value=' "+token_val+" '...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( window ).on( "load", function(){
    var token_val= document.getElementsByName("token")[0].value;

    var real_data = "<input type='hidden' name='token' value='" + token_val + "'>";

    $('form').append(real_data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

change your code with the below one

```
  $( window ).on( "load", function(){
            var token_val= document.getElementsByName("token")[0].value;

            var real_data = "<input type='hidden' name='token' value='"+token_val+"'>";

            $('form').append(real_data);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's object-based approach to creating elements.

```
var real_data = $('<input>', {
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'token',
    value: token_val
});
$('form').append(real_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have beaten me to the answer, but if you fancy being progressive and using [ES2015](https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-template-strings), you could use template strings:

```
let real_data = `<input type="hidden" name="token" value="${token_val}">`
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan whoops, typo :-|)